# Difference between mapping of a List and an Object type in ElasticSearch

Tags: java, json, elasticsearch

In elastic search for both List type and Object type we write

```
"type": "nested",
"properties": {
    //properties....
}
```

So how elastic search differentiate between them?

Difference between mapping of a List and an Object type in ElasticSearch.

Comment: What happen to text!!!!!

Comment: phaberest why u edited this!!!.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The nested type is a specialized version of the object datatype that allows arrays of objects to be indexed and queried independently of each other.

According to docs Lucene has no concept of inner objects, so Elasticsearch flattens object hierarchies into a simple list of field names and values.

Elasticsearch converted List into a nested type (arrays of objects) object internally and process them as nested type.

Answer (score 0):

List is stored as `field` nested objects are stored as an independent `document` which the parent one has somekind of a pointer pointing to it.

Comment: Can you give example ?